# Error in executing mysql code with python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Hey I'm making my project and I've written this code. But this is giving me this error. It would be very helpful for me if you can help me with tis to find the solution.

here's my code.

```
import mysql.connector as cntr
db = cntr.connect(host = 'localhost' , user = 'root' , passwd = '2004')
db.autocommit = True
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS shop_management")
cur.execute("create database if not exists shop_management")
cur.execute("use shop_management")
cur.execute("""create table if not exists stock
(Book_No bigint primary key,
Book_Name varchar(255),
Author varchar(255),
Publisher varchar(255),
Cost_per_Book float,
Available_Stock bigint,
qty_purchased bigint,
purchased_on date)""")
cur.execute("create table if not exists users(username varchar(255) , password varchar(255) , check (username <> 'ADMIN'))")
cur.execute("create table if not exists purchased (Book_no bigint , purchased_on date , foreign key(Book_no) references stock(Book_No))")
cur.execute("create unique index Book_Index on stock(Book_No)")
cur.execute("insert into users values('ADMIN' , 'admin@123')")
print("Database and Tables created successfully")
c = input("Press any key to continue-----> ")
cur.close()
db.close()
```

And it's giving me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\CBSE 12\cs projects\Tables_in_mysql.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.execute("insert into users values('ADMIN' , 'admin@123')")
  File "C:\Python 37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 568, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Python 37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 846, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Python 37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 656, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'users_chk_1' is violated.
```

Comment: `3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'users_chk_1' is violated.` Which table is that?

Comment: either remove ` check (username <> 'ADMIN'))` from the create table, or change 'ADMIN'  to something else in the `insert into users`.  it is not a python problem.  you have created a constraint that requires username to be anything by 'ADMIN' and you are trying to insert username of 'ADMIN'.  if anything your code is actually working correctly.